# Jersey - Return customised error instead of stack trace when url has special characters

Tags: spring-boot, jersey-2.0

My Http Request Url has some special character like - 
../MyOrder(Id='1234')?{@sleep(15)}

I am using following tech stack - 
Jersey + Spring Boot and tomcat as server

Now I want this url to return some customized error instead of returning stack trace, I have tried Exception Mapper , here is the code 
@Provider
public class JsonProcessingExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper{

```
    public static class Error {
        public String key;
        public String message;
    }

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(IllegalArgumentException exception) {
        Error error = new Error();
        error.key = "bad-json";
        error.message = exception.getMessage();
        return Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(error).build();
    }
```

}

but in with it , or without this , I am getting following stack trace -

Apache Tomcat/7.0.54 - Error report

## HTTP Status 500 - Illegal character "@" at position 1 is not allowed as a start of a name in a path template "{@sleep(15)}$format=json".

**type** Exception report

**message** Illegal character "@" at position 1 is not allowed as a start of a name in a path template "{@sleep(15)}$format=json".

**description** The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

**exception** <***pre>java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character "@" at position 1 is not allowed as a start of a name in a path template "{@sleep(15)}$format=json".
    org.glassfish.jersey.uri.internal.UriTemplateParser.parseName(UriTemplateParser.java:305)***
    org.glassfish.jersey.uri.internal.UriTemplateParser.parse(UriTemplateParser.java:235)
    org.glassfish.jersey.uri.internal.UriTemplateParser.<init>(UriTemplateParser.java:107)
    org.glassfish.jersey.uri.UriTemplate.createURIComponent(UriTemplate.java:891)
    org.glassfish.jersey.uri.UriTemplate.createURIWithStringValues(UriTemplate.java:858)
    org.glassfish.jersey.uri.UriTemplate.createURIWithStringValues(UriTemplate.java:797)
    org.glassfish.jersey.uri.UriTemplate.createURI(UriTemplate.java:762)
    org.glassfish.jersey.uri.internal.JerseyUriBuilder._build(JerseyUriBuilder.java:893)
    org.glassfish.jersey.uri.internal.JerseyUriBuilder.build(JerseyUriBuilder.java:810)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:330)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:219)
    org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:110)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextFilterConfiguration$1.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:257)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:186)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)

**note** The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomca